# How can I get the maximum value from a field?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Please help me use the Max function. I am very new to Access and SQL.

I have the table below and I need the maximum value from the meter_read field. In this case 1000 is the maximum value because it has add factor of 2000. If I am doing max on meter_read it's giving me 1000.

```
Factor    meter_Read
1         4500
1         5500
100       3500
100       2500
1000      1500
2000      1000
```

Comment: I'm confused. You want the meter_Read value on the row with the maximum Factor value?

Comment: Thanks Michael, I want the query to show just 1000, hope it will make sense

Comment: PlayDeezGames please help

Comment: There are a number of possibilities, eg, `dlookup("meter_Read", "meters", "Factor=DMax('Factor','meters')")`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT top 1 meter_Read FROM yourtablename order by meter_read DESC
```

should give you 5500

Comment: As I mentioned above I need 1000 because 1000 in the maximum value in this table because meter read multiply with add factor.

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the value of `meter_Read` corresponding to the max value of `Factor`:

```
select meter_Read
from MyTable
where Factor = (
  select max(Factor)
  from MyTable
)
```